# How do i drag item from QListWidget and drop to QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtcore

[image: Qt]

As shown in the image on the left side i have a QListWidget named "my_listwidget" populated with 3 commands and on the right side i have a QPlainTextEdit named "my_textedit".

i am able to drag from QListWidget by using this code

```
ui->block_commands_listwidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
ui->block_commands_listwidget->setDragEnabled(true);
ui->block_commands_listwidget ->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDrop);
ui->block_commands_listwidget->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(false);
ui->block_commands_listwidget->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
```

But i am not able to drop into my QPlainTextEdit, i guess because when i drag, its of "item type" and when im trying to drop into textbox, the QPlainTextEdit accepts only Text but not item type. 
How do i do this ?
Thanks for going through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple: QPlaintTextEdit does not recognize the mimetype that the QListWidget sends by default, so the solution is to override the [`mimeData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#mimeData) method adding the text of the selected items as plain text:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class ListWidget: public QListWidget{
public:
    using QListWidget::QListWidget;
protected:
    QMimeData *mimeData(const QList<QListWidgetItem *> items) const
    {
        QMimeData *md = QListWidget::mimeData(items);
        QStringList texts;
        for(QListWidgetItem *item : selectedItems())
            texts << item->text();
        md->setText(texts.join(QStringLiteral("\n")));
        return md;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    ListWidget *lw = new ListWidget;
    lw->addItems({"First Command", "Second Command", "Third Command"});
    lw->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    lw->setDragEnabled(true);
    lw->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragOnly);
    QPlainTextEdit *pe = new QPlainTextEdit;
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(&w);
    lay->addWidget(lw);
    lay->addWidget(pe);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can i do this by , `void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("text/uri-list"))
        event->acceptProposedAction();
}`

Comment: Hello Again, The drag and drop is working fine as expected but since i subclassed QListWidget and created the QListWidget using this code                                                     ui->block_commands_listwidget = new ListWidget(ui->centralwidget);   i am not able to implement Single click and double click functionalities.

Comment: @Mr_Workalot 1) You should not do `ui->block_commands_listwidget = new ListWidget(ui->centralwidget);` but promote the widget, read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html for more information, with the above you should no longer have problems, 2) If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]

Comment: Thanks so much for the instruction,
As per your suggestion, what I have done is, in my Eclipse I have added a new Header file named Header.h, this Header.h file contains `class ListWidget`  , Then In my Qt Designer I right clicked my desired QListWidget(block_command_listwidget) and promoted it, In the class name entry, I put ListWidget and header name entry, I put Header.h. and its working fine, 

Thanks so much QT Master @eyllanesc.

Comment: Also, i want to show "Pause Command" in QListwidget but after i drag "Pause Command"  from QListWidget, i want "\n<Pause seconds=\"10\" />" to appear in my QTextedit,       , so  how can i achieve this , so far i know that i can use a Key-Value pair Map and i have this code  `map<string, string> commands;`

    `commands["Pause Command"] = "\n<Pause seconds=\"10\" />";
    map<string, string>::iterator it;
    it = commands.find(item->text());
    return it->second;`                        any way to tweak the class you posted before and acheive this,  Thanks